# Opening nautilus from vifm

Tags: vifm

If I browse to a folder in VIFM, is there a way to open a nautilus window from that location?  I'm interested in this so I can use point-and-click drag and dropping features of nautilus in certain contexts (vifm is the most efficient way to *find* a location, but it isn't necessarily the most efficient way to manipulate files/folders within that location, or so it seems to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vifm you can set custom commands with:

```
:command name action
```

So by setting a command like:

```
:command [name-you-wish] nautilus .
```

every time you type

```
:[name-you-wish]
```

nautilus will open the current directory.

For example:

```
:command oin nautilus .
:oin
```

Comment: Alternative/additional way is to bind it to a key, e.g. `nnoremap ,e :!nautilus .<cr>`. It's a bit faster if it's a common task.